# How can I find the domain and determine if the function is even or odd or neither of a piecewise function defined by absolute value.

Tags: functions

How can I find the domain of the domain of the following function and how can I study boundedness :
$$\theta(x) = \begin{cases}
|x - 3| & \text{if $-5<x<-1$}, \\
|x| + 1 & \text{if $-1\leq x<5$.}
\end{cases} $$
And how can I study if the function is even or odd or neither? shall I change the inequalities when substituting $-x$ for $x$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The domain is given in the definition of the function.  The function is defined when $x\in (-5,5)$, which gives the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The domain is simply the values of $x$ for which you can evaluate your function, in this case you can evaluate $\theta (x) $ for every $x$ in  $(-5,-1)$ with the first case and for every $x$ in $[-1,5)$ in the second case.

So the domain is $ (-5,-1) \cup [-1,5) = (-5,5) $

Comment: What about studying whether the function is even or odd or neither, shall I change the inequalities in the question after substitution ?

Comment: You need to check if $f(x)=f(-x)$ for every $x$ in the domain $(-5,5)$

Comment: Shall I write $\theta (-x) = |-x-3| $ when -5 <-x<-1 or this is wrong?

Comment: Wrong. If $-5<x<-1$ then $1<-x<5$ and so to evaluate the function for $-x$ you have to use the second definition. Compare this value to the one of simply evaluating and you'll have your answer

Comment: How can I study boundedness?

Comment: what do you mean by saying this sentence " Compare this value to the one of simply evaluating"?

Comment: to the value of $ \theta (x) $